# Strange characters in neo4j REST response

Tags: http, unicode, character-encoding, neo4j

**I am using neo4j's REST interface to query the database. However, text is not being transmitted correctly. The one of the properties on a node is a long string of text. When I view the text through the neo4j's browser, the string looks like this:**

???initialComments:true! pubdate:07/21/2011 07:05 EDT! commentPeriod:3! commentEndDate:7/24/11 7:5 EDT! currentDate:2/4/14 7:0 EST! allowComments:false! displayComments:true! Study raises questions on Medicaid signups New York Mayor Michael R. Bloomberg announced Thursday that he will donate $50 million to the Sierra Club to support its nationwide campaign to eliminate coal-fired power plants. Sierra Club executive director Michael Brune described the gift from Bloomberg Philanthropies, to be spread over four years, as “a game-changer, from our perspective.”

**However, when I use the REST interface to get the data, the string looks like this:**

\t\t\t  \n  ???initialComments:true! pubdate:07/21/2011 07:05 EDT! commentPeriod:3! commentEndDate:7/24/11 7:5 EDT! currentDate:2/4/14 7:0 EST! allowComments:false! displayComments:true!\n      \t  \t\t  \t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\n  \t\t  \t\t\tStudy raises questions on Medicaid signups  \t\t\t\n  \t\t\n  \t\t\t  \t\t\t  \t\t\t  \t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t  \t\t\t\t New York Mayor Michael R. Bloomberg announced Thursday that he will donate $50 million to the Sierra Club to support its nationwide campaign to eliminate coal-fired power plants.\n  \t\t\t\t\t\tSierra Club executive director Michael Brune described the gift from Bloomberg Philanthropies, to be spread over four years, as â€œa game-changer, from our perspective.

---

Double quotes are renderd as â€œ. I don't know where the \t and \n characters are coming from. What is the solution? Do I need to set MIME-headers, or convert the string to a different character set?

Environment:

- Linux (Heroku)
- node.js
- node-neo4j as the node.js -> neo4j interface
- GrapheneDB as the neo4j platform (running either v2.0 or v2.0.1 of neo4j)

Comment: What is the code you are using to call the API? It looks like you are interpreting a response as plain text in ISO-8859-1 encoding. Neo4j returns JSON, in UTF-8 encoding, so you should be feeding a JSON parser directly with the output.

Comment: @bobince Updated questions with environment details

Comment: where is your raw data coming from? what does it look like if you look at it in an 7bit ascii editor? did you set `content-type:application/json;charset=utf8` ?

Comment: @Michael. I did set the content type to application/json. I'm using node.js with Express and according the the docs, the charset defaults to utf8. For now, I'm filtering out the junk characters. It's kludgy, but it's the best I can do for now.